# Color and state changing after button press tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-button, python-3.12

I want to change the button's color after pressing it(red normal state 0, green active state 1) is there a way to do that with tkinter?

For clarity I do not mean the color changing while pressing button(I am aware of "activebackground="COLOR")"

Edit: Using tk.Button() currently

Comment: It is not clear what kind of button you used, normal tkinter `Button` or `ttk.Button`, as the way to change the background color of them are different.  So it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for telling me I will clear that up

Comment: If `tk.Button` is used, simply call `.config(bg="...")` to change its background color inside the callback of `command` option.

Comment: I would also need to edit the statevariable would that be posisble as command= {button.config(bg="..") and stateval = 1}

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want without a [mre].

Comment: To clarify: are you just looking to create a button that toggles between two colors when clicked as a way of indicating a toggle "state", or are you actually looking to modify the button's `state` attribute, i.e. `'normal'` / `'disabled'`, etc.?